# Not return to dialogfragment after fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have Fragment1. On them, i pressed button and start DialogFramgent. On DialogFragment i pressed button and start Fragment2. When i pressed back, i am return to Fragment1, but not to DialogFragmnet

Comment: please, provide Your code for fragments start.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the fragment to the backstack.  A call addToBackStack() should solve the problem. Straight from the documentation: "This back stack is managed by the activity and allows the user to return to the previous fragment state, by pressing the Back  button". See for details:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Jasper

Answer (score 0):

A great feature about using fragments in your activity is the ability to add, remove, replace, and perform other actions with them, in response to user interaction. Each set of changes that you commit to the activity is called a transaction and you can perform one using APIs in FragmentTransaction. You can also save each transaction to a back stack managed by the activity, allowing the user to navigate backward through the fragment changes (similar to navigating backward through activities).

You can acquire an instance of FragmentTransaction from the FragmentManager like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

Each transaction is a set of changes that you want to perform at the same time. You can set up all the changes you want to perform for a given transaction using methods such as add(), remove(), and replace(). Then, to apply the transaction to the activity, you must call commit().

Before you call commit(), however, you might want to call addToBackStack(), in order to add the transaction to a back stack of fragment transactions. This back stack is managed by the activity and allows the user to return to the previous fragment state, by pressing the Back button.